# git branch not acting as expected

Tags: git

I ran git checkout -b "new branch"

I made changes, saved in atom.

I went back to master. Somehow changes were made to master as well.

I run git status, yup same files changed.

I ran git checkout -- . to erase working directory, back to normal.

edit: For a while, every change I was making to a branch showed up in master. Now it looks like it's back to normal. I don't know if I had a stroke, or if there was a temporary bug. Anyways, thanks to SO community, helpful as always.

edit: It had everything to do with me not committing changes in the branch before checking out master. I knew I was at fault.

Comment: Did you commit before you checked out master?

Comment: You didn't commit anything. Uncommitted changes are not in any branch. They are only in your working tree (and in the index if you have run `git add` but it seems you haven't). On branch switching Git tries to preserve the uncommitted changes, if they don't conflict with the changes introduced by the newly checked out branch. Unless you know exactly what you're doing, it's recommended to not switch branches if `git status` does not report a clean working tree ("nothing to commit").

Comment: When you ran `git checkout -- .` you discarded the changes you did. You have lost them because you didn't commit them (as you can see, they are not on `master` or on `new branch`).

Answer (score 2):

When you checked out `git checkout -B new_branch` you're in fact on another branch. The changes you made there however also need to be committed as well.

So before checking out *back* to master, you should run `git add path/to/file` or `git add .` to add your changes. Then, once you collected all the changes you want to commit, run

`git commit -m "your commit message"`.

Now you will have the following situation

```
master ----- A - B
new_branch -------\ - C
```

Once you're back on your master, you have the option to merge the changes by running

`git merge my_branch`

Then your state is:

```
master ----- A - B ---- / -- C
new_branch -------\ - C
```

I hope that clears it up.

Comment: After adding the files, you could also do `git stash save "<Informative Message here>"` in order to save changes and come back to them later.

Comment: That is true. Feel free to add an edit to this answer with more detailed information :) I barely use stash (Just for keeping changes for a few minutes when I have to hop between different branches) so I am sure I would miss some important information.